# How do I navigate from one user control to another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I have A.XAML and B.XAML .

I want to navigate from A to B when I click on a button in page A.

```
<Button  Grid.Row="2" Content="View Sequence"  command={binding myCommand} />
```

So , Inside myCommand , I want to right the logic to navigate to B.XAML and want to set the data context either by using commandparameter or any better alternates available.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: I think this is a simple solution: http://www.csharpcity.com/usercontrolpage-navigation-architecture-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Avalon Wizard project.

Link to project: [http://avalonwizard.codeplex.com](http://avalonwizard.codeplex.com/)

Link to tutorial: http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/how-to-use-wpf-avalonwizard-control-i/